# Is any another way to pass data from child to nested parent component(6 level up) without using of emit and store in vuejs?

Tags: vue.js, components, vue-component, vuex

I need to pass data from child to parent(nested) component, I know we can do this with `emit` or `store` but I want to know, Is any other way, for doing this in a better manner?

I don't want to use `emit` just because my parent component is 6 levels up.

Comment: provide/inject. For global data, a store is perfectly ok

Answer (score 3):

Store doesn't necessary need to be `vuex` or `pinia`. It can be an external `reactive()`, imported in all the components which use it, regardless of their relation.

Think of it as a `data: () => ({})` object, but without the component. Here's an example where I'm creating a simple reactive *"store"*, and injecting it in both App and Child (6 levels deep).

```js
const { createApp, reactive, defineComponent } = Vue;

const store = reactive({
  foo: 'bar'
})
const app = createApp({
  setup: () => ({ store })
});

app.component('parent', defineComponent({
  template: '<div class="parent">Parent<br><slot></slot></div>'
}));
app.component('child', defineComponent({
  setup: () => ({ store }),
  template: '<input v-model="store.foo">'
}));

app.mount('#app')
```

```css
.parent .parent {
  padding-left: 1rem;
}
input {
  margin-left: 1rem;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@3/dist/vue.global.prod.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <parent>
    <parent>
      <parent>
        <parent>
          <parent>
            <child />
          </parent>
        </parent>
      </parent>
    </parent>
  </parent>
  <pre v-text="store" />
</div>
```

Same thing, in Vue2:

```js
const store = Vue.observable({
  foo: 'bar'
})

Vue.component('parent', {
  template: '<div class="parent">Parent<br><slot /></div>'
});
Vue.component('child', {
  computed: {
    store: () => store
  },
  template: '<input v-model="store.foo">'
});

new Vue({
  computed: {
    store: () => store
  }
}).$mount('#app')
```

```css
.parent .parent {
  padding-left: 1rem;
}
input {
  margin-left: 1rem;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.6.14"></script>
<div id="app">
  <parent>
    <parent>
      <parent>
        <parent>
          <parent>
            <child />
          </parent>
        </parent>
      </parent>
    </parent>
  </parent>
  <pre v-text="store" />
</div>
```

In a real app, you would have the "store" defined in a file and imported in any component using it. (e.g:

```
import { reactive } from 'vue'
export const myStore = reactive({
  //...stuff
})

anywhere else: 
import { myStore } from './path/to/store'
```

Note: If you're using Vue2, you can import `reactive` from `@vue/composition-api` plugin or you can use `Vue.observable()` instead. It provides the same functionality.

Even if the above works, the more you use it, the more you would actually benefit from using `pinia` or `vuex`, as they come with the great benefit of being integrated with vue devtools. giving you the ability to inspect, roll back or replay changes to your reactive state. Not to mention you can also define actions on the store, so you don't have to scatter them around multiple components, especially useful when you want to perform the same action from two or more different components.

---

Another option is to use [provide/inject](https://vuejs.org/guide/components/provide-inject.html) developed specifically for bypassing the parent/child chain. It's useful when you want to provide specifically for the descendants of the current component, but not to descendants of its siblings. For example:

```
item-1
  component
    component
      child-1
item-2
  component
    component
      child-2
      child-3
```

In the above case, if you want `child-2` and `child-3` to inherit/update `item-2` but not affect `item-1`, then you would use `provide` in `item-2` and `inject` in `child-2` and `child-3`.

I personally haven't used inject/provide, as I find working with external stores quite powerful. Even when, in theory, I have a case like the above. I use one single store where I uniquely identify ancestors. The grand children use that identifier to update the appropriate ancestor in the store.

In fact, the only place where i use `emit` is in agnostic components, which can have any parent, take some input, perform some action and then update their parent (e.g: the context). A good such example are generic form components which don't have to know anything about the parent form.
Another such example are agonstic list renderers, which, again, don't care what they list. They "emit" the click action to the parent component which knows what that click actually means.

Answer (score 1):

you can use eventBus for this purpose.
[Here is a working demo.](https://codesandbox.io/s/focused-panka-8w60xc?file=/src/components/HelloWorld.vue)

Comment: Yes but as per my understanding event bus is not good practice due to its antipattern that is why we should be avoided it as much as possible, and also not recommended by experts.